# Django allauth customize email template and add some personal image

Tags: image, templates, django-allauth

In a Django Project of [`Django-allath`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth), I'm overriding the Django confirmed [email template](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/allauth/templates/account/email) and HTML shows correctly.

My question is how to add a personal image in it?

I put the image into the Django app static path:`static/images/imn0.png` and I add the image by this way: `<img  src={% static 'images/img0.png' %}`,

-------What I have done for the issue  ------

I also added the tags `{% load account %}{% user_display user as user_display %}{% load static i18n %}`

-------What I think in this issue  ------

Actually,I have seen the difference between the urls:I can get the images of Django in the static file by:'0.0.0.0:**8000**/static/images'.However, when I open the email template in allauth ,it tries to get the images in '0.0.0.0:**8025**/static/images'.This is the reason why I failed.But I don't know how to fix it.[image: the error message shown in the browser]
I can't understand the existing problem that prevents this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!!! I can solve it.

If you want to add some personal images(icons) to your custom template, you can byte image .([http://imgbase64.duoshitong.com/](http://location%20in%20here)).and use the src = "". It will be work.